# Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running java from NodeJs

Tags: java, node.js, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to execute a jar file from nodeJs, I've been using both child_proces.exec and child_process.spawn. with both cases I'm receiving this error:
**Error: Exception in thread "main"
Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ftdi/FTDevice**

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 with java, jdk, etc' installed.

Here is my code:

***using exec:***

```
var exeprocess = exec('java -Djava.library.path=./ftd2xx.so -jar DenkoviRelayCommandLineTool_10.jar DAE000dY 4 2 1');
```

***using spawn:***

```
var proc = spawn('java', 
                [   '-jar',
                    '-Djava.library.path=./ftd2xx.so',
                    'DenkoviRelayCommandLineTool_10.jar',
                    'DAE000dY ','4','2','1'
                ]);
```

I've figure out that both cases can't locate classes in ft2xx.so, but why?
b.t.w: double check that the command/locations are correct and the exact same script work perfectly in terminal

Comment: where is your class FTDevice define? Is it in some other jar?

Comment: I'm guessing ftd2xx.so

Comment: No IMHO it cant be .so i feel...

Comment: you're right it's in another jar JavaFTD2XX-0.2.5.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add `-classpath <path of jar>/JavaFTD2XX-0.2.5.jar` to your exec or spawn to avoid NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to copy the lib folder to nodeJs location